# Navigation / Links in HTML

Tags: html, hyperlink, navigation

Hoe moet je link maken in html? en verder?

---

How to make navigation link in html?

Comment: Can you please rewrite your question in english?

Comment: Google [says](http://translate.google.com/translate_t?hl=&ie=UTF-8&text=document&sl=en&tl=iw#auto|en|Hoe%20moet%20je%20link%20maken%20in%20html%3F%20en%20verder%3F%0A) `How do you create a link in html? and beyond?`

Comment: @Martin this is not a requirement on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please put at least some effort in your questions, any relevant google search would have resulted in your answer. Furthermore, always ask questions in english.

Comment: @Radek S: I didn't say it's a requirement. I simply asked if the OP could rewrite it in english.

Comment: @mellamokb http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow

Comment: @Radek But if the question has to be translated to be understood by the rest of the community (read: majority), by your argument, the answers should be run through a translator as well?

Comment: @Radek: Lol, I found that exact post... looks like English is the accepted universal, but not necessarily required.

Comment: @Linux Kleen maybe a nice feature-request: automatic translation? There is a Google Translation API.

Comment: @Radek Haha. It's *Linus*. Not Linux. But you're right. Maybe suggest that on meta?

Comment: Hey, dude, you have an operating system named after you. Oh... hang on... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

As I understood from your original post:

```
<a href="link.html">This is a link</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171968/navigatie-links-in-html">woco's link</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

To create a text link

```
<a href="targetpage.html">Your Link</a>
```

---

To create an image link

```
<a href="targetpage.html">
  <img src="image-file.jpg">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think we can manage a longer explanation.

A link takes the form `<a href="target">caption</a>`. That's the really simplistic way to look at things. `target` can be a number of things:

- [An anchor within the current document](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_name.asp). So if you, at some point on the page, write `<a name="anchor">` then `<a href="#anchor">go to anchor</a>` takes you there. In XHTML this should be `<a id="anchor"/>` rather than `name`. This is, in my opinion, one of *the* overlooked features of html, originally designed to make *navigating documents easier*.
- It can be an absolute URI, like `mailto:enquiries@mysite.com` or `ftp://downloads.somesite.com`. It doesn't have to be `http://` although the most common use *is* with `http`. You are free, in fact, to use `file://`.
- It can be a relative URI. So for example you might link to `<a href="../users">Users</a>` in which case `stackoverflow.com/questions/123456` would go to `stackoverflow.com/users`.
- If you specify `<base href="http://someurl" />` then everything in terms of relative addressing, the point above, becomes relative to that base *I believe*. I don't use it much.

Now, as others have observed, caption can contain other items. Literally anything, say `<img/>` or `<div></div>` or `<li>`. The last case gives you a way to create css menus; how to do that is another question, but the point is, this is pretty powerful.

`<a>` has some other properties, specifically `target` The most commonly used one is `target="_blank"` which asks the browser to open up a new window. You can use this with html frames too, but if you don't know what frames are, forget I mentioned them. Really.